# Loop in R to produce graph for every combination of variables of different length

Tags: r, function, loops

I am trying to create a function that will produce an individual plot comparing two linear regressions for type = "Plot" to type = "Strata". This comparison of linear models must be made for each unique combination of BCR # and LC type. For example (LC = UC and BCR = 30,LC = UC and BCR = 29,LC = UC and BCR = 28...once the LC "UC" has been compared for each unique BCR then the loop should move on to the next LC type and compare it against all BCR #s). Below is my data frame:

```
> head(Plot_BCR)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
   Year   BCR LC      Area type 
  <dbl> <int> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1  2001    30 UC    0      Plot 
2  2001    30 OW    0      Plot 
3  2001    30 D1    0.0126 Plot 
4  2001    30 D2    0      Plot 
5  2001    30 D3    0      Plot 
6  2001    30 D4    0      Plot 

> unique(Plot_BCR$LC)
 [1] "UC" "OW" "D1" "D2" "D3" "D4" "BL" "DF" "EF" "MF" "SS" "H"  "HP" "CC" "WW" "EW"

> unique(Plot_BCR$BCR)
[1]  30  29  28  14  13 100  27  31
```

I have created the following function and nested loop to create each unique combination, however my output only produces a graph for each LC type but ONLY for the last BCR # (#31).

```
comparison.graph <- function(Plot_BCR, na.rm=TRUE, ...){
  
  BCR <- unique(Plot_BCR$BCR)
  LC <- unique(Plot_BCR$LC)
  
  for (i in seq_along(LC)){
    for (j in seq_along(BCR))
    plot <-
      ggplot(subset(Plot_BCR, Plot_long$LC == LC[i] & BCR == BCR[j]), aes(x = Year, y = Area, group=type))+
      geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x)+
      ggtitle(paste(LC[i], BCR[j], sep="-"))
    
    print(plot)
  }
}

comparison.graph(Plot_BCR)
```

Any help with my function that will have it create a plot for every combination of LC and BCR # would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get generate a list of plots using `split` + `lapply` approach.

```
library(ggplot2)

comparison.graph <- function(Plot_BCR, na.rm=TRUE, ...){
  
  lapply(split(Plot_BCR, list(Plot_BCR$LC,Plot_BCR$BCR)), function(data) {
    ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Area, group=type)) +
      geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~x)+
      ggtitle(paste(data$LC[1], data$BCR[1], sep="-"))
  })
}

list_plots <- comparison.graph(Plot_BCR)
```

We `split` the data into list of dataframes where each dataframe is a combination of unique value of `LC` and `BCR` and plot the data for every dataframe. The individual plots can be accessed via `[[` i.e `list_plots[[1]]`, `list_plots[[2]]` etc.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much.