# R ggplot for every combination of x in data frame/table

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a series of comparative graphs using ggplot. See data example below:

```
Test <- data.frame(Group = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), y = 1:7)
ggplot(data = Test, aes(x=Group, y= y)) +
  geom_point
```

When I run this code, I get a single plot with all Groups on the x axis but I would like to simply have two groups present per graph. I.e graph 1 is a vs b, graph 2 is a vs c, graph 3 is a vs d ...

I have tried several combinations looking at:
[Loop in R to produce graph for every combination of variables of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578555/loop-in-r-to-produce-graph-for-every-combination-of-variables-of-different-lengt)

```
comparison.graph <- function(Test, na.rm=TRUE, ...){
  
  lapply(split(Test, list(Test$Group)), function(data) {
    ggplot(data, aes(x=Group, y= y)) +
geom_point()
  })
}

list_plots <- comparison.graph(Test)
```

However, the code above gives me a list of every graph with a single X meaning I get seven graphs where the x ranges from a to g rather than giving the combinations.

In addition, I would like to easily find the graph that represents the desired combination. For example, I want to show the graph combination c,g without using the index since the group lettering might change.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use pairwise [correlation function](https://r-coder.com/correlation-plot-r/), such as `graphics::pairs` ? Eg `Test %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from=Group, values_from=y) %>% pairs`

Comment: The reason is that my data is looking at average of points scored. I.e. How did player a compare to player b? I am not looking for a correlation but rather comparing the highs and lows of points scored in the season